# How do I re-do this command using the [] operator for the nesting?

Tags: json, rethinkdb

I just started with RethinkDB and I love it. I have successfully got this command to work on json data:

```
r.db("test").table("gleif").filter({"lei:LEIRecord": {
"lei:Entity": { 
"lei:HeadquartersAddress": { 
        "lei:City":  "Toronto"  
}
}
}
}).pluck({"lei:LEIRecord": {"lei:Entity": "lei:LegalName"}})
```

But this returns data in a json like manner. I would like to use the [] operator to simplify the query and see what type of data it returns. However, I can't seem to get the [] operator to work. I am sure you can read it, but I am filtering on the city of Toronto, but only want the LegalName returned. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, for doc

```
{id: "toront", 
  "lei:LEIRecord": {
    "lei:Entity": { 
      "lei:LegalName": "TorontoTest",
      "lei:HeadquartersAddress": { 
        "lei:City":  "Toronto"  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

by using your query you want instead of this

```
[{"id": "toront" ,
    "lei:LEIRecord": {
        "lei:Entity": {
            "lei:HeadquartersAddress": {
                "lei:City": "Toronto"
            } ,
            "lei:LegalName": "TorontoTest"
        }
    }  
}]
```

get only "lei:LegalName" like this:

```
[{"lei:LegalName":"TorontoTest"}]
```

If so, then you can use map:

```
r.db("test").table("gleif").filter(
  {"lei:LEIRecord": {
    "lei:Entity": { 
      "lei:HeadquartersAddress": { 
        "lei:City":  "Toronto" 
      }
    }
  }
}).map(function(doc){
  return {"lei:LegalName": doc("lei:LEIRecord")("lei:Entity")("lei:LegalName")};
})
```

If you want to get just array of names, like this:

```
["TorontoTest"]
```

you can use this query:

```
r.db("test").table("gleif").filter(
  {"lei:LEIRecord": {
    "lei:Entity": { 
      "lei:HeadquartersAddress": { 
        "lei:City":  "Toronto" 
      }
    }
  }
}).map(function(doc){
  return doc("lei:LEIRecord")("lei:Entity")("lei:LegalName");
})
```

Comment: Very cool. Both worked brilliantly. I will study this to figure out why it worked. Thank you.